# Deja-Dup - send message after backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Is it possible to send automatically mail or message via TCP port when backup is made by Deja Dup and when backups are scheduled eg. weekly.

Comment: If you want to report a bug/suggest a feature please visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup . AskUbuntu is not a bugtracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no, this is not possible. It looks like the developers of this app aim for as little configurability as possible. Look yourself at the [Deja-Dup Bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup).